# Mac Sandbox entitlement for Asus Xtion : Failed to open the file

Tags: macos, usb, sandbox, entitlements, asus-xtion

I am developing a Mac application that uses an Asus Xtion Pro Live camera. I activate Sandboxing and set the com.apple.security.device.usb entitlement to YES.

After doing so, the app is not able to detect the camera anymore.

```
Could not open "1d27/0601@253/5": Failed to open the file!
```

Does anyone know how to set an entitlement to enable detection of the Asus Xtion Pro Live?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The above problem was solved adding an entitlement:

```
com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write
```

for the file (found using the mac console):

```
/private/tmp/XnCore.Mutex.HostProtocolMutex1d27_0601@250_6.key
```

The problem now is that Mac Sandboxing does not allow IPC System V Semaphores.

```
27/06/14 12:17:50,000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: MyApp(69513) deny ipc-sysv-sem
```

Does anyone know how to use IPC System V Semaphores in Mac Sandboxed apps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

what about `com.apple.security.device.camera`? [All available entitlement in the reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW11).